# Perform an exact match with an if statement

Tags: php

I'm working on setting up a condition on my web page whereby 1 of 2 things may happen;

1) The user posts a youtube link by itself, no other text, and that link is turned into an embeded video on the page.

2) Any other kind of post is posted as a regular message, skipping everything in the preceding condition.

I have some syntax set up that posts embeded video just fine (first condition), posts text and creates clickable hyperlinks just fine (second condition), but fails if someone tries to post a youtube link along with any other text.  It fails because the code that controls condition 1 is not specific enough.  Both conditions are processed like this;

```
if(strpos($message,"youtube.com/watch?v="))
    {
    $message = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="' . str_replace('/watch?v=','/embed/',$message) . '"></iframe>';
    mysqli_query($db_conn,"insert into feed_messages (userid, subject, message) values ('$useridvalue', '$subject', '$message');") 
    or die("".mysql_error());

    $messageid = mysqli_query($db_conn,"select last_insert_id();") or die("".mysql_error());
    $messageidvaluearray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($messageid);
    $messageidvalue = implode(" " , $messageidvaluearray);


    mysqli_query($db_conn,"insert into feed_recipients (messageid, userid) values ('$messageidvalue', '$useridvalue');") 
or die("".mysql_error());
    foreach($_SESSION['recipientlist'] as $recipient) 
    mysqli_query($db_conn,"insert into feed_recipients (messageid, userid) values ('$messageidvalue', '$recipient');");

    header('Refresh: 0; URL=mypage.php');
    }
else
    {
    function make_links_clickable($message)
    {
        return preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1" target="_blank" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE"><b>$1</b></a>', 
$message);
    }

    $message = make_links_clickable($message);
```

My question is; how can I make the first if statement more strict so that if it only sees the string "youtube.com/watch?v=" alone, then it executes its code block, otherwise if it see anything else accompanying it, then it can be processed by the else statement?

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: `if($message === "youtube.com/watch?v=")`

Comment: Hi Mark, can a wildcard be added at the end of the link?  This statement is too specific.  If the link, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=examplevideo is put in a message, I would like the statment to match right up to the = sign.

Comment: In that case, `if(strpos($message,"youtube.com/watch?v=") === 0)` will match if $message consists of __or__ begins with "youtube.com/watch?v="

Comment: Hi Mark, this statement does not work.  If "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=examplevideo" is the only text in $message, it be changed by the if statement.  But, if "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=examplevideo" consists of any other text either before or after it in $message, then it should be passed to the second statement to be treated as a hyperlink.  Is there a wildcard that can be used either before or after "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" that can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out how to fix this issue.  Thankfully, youtube is pretty consistent in the length of its links and the patterns of its URLs.

1) Its hyperlink length, including "https://www.youtube.com/watch?w=" tends to be around 43 to 44 characters long.  However, this is not too unique.  PHP.net's own hyperlinks, for example, can be this long and we do not want to use embed those links.

2) The other factor, which makes the youtube hyperlinks unique for obvious reasons, is the afformentioned "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" pattern.

Using these two characteristics, we can create strlen and strpos statements that will look for anything simply posted as a youtube link in a message.  The code will turn the video in the link of that message into an embeded video.  If the poster puts anything else in the message, it will become a hyperlink instead.  Here is the code;

```
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conn, $_POST['message']);
$youtubecheck = strlen($message);

if (($youtubecheck == '43') || ($youtubecheck == '44') && strpos($message, "youtube.com/watch?v="))
    {
    $message = '<iframe width="535" height="400" src="' . str_replace('/watch?v=','/embed/',$message) . '"></iframe>';
    }
else
    {
    function make_links_clickable($message)
    {
    return preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1" target="_blank" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE"><b>$1</b></a>', 
$message);
    }
    $message = make_links_clickable($message);
```

Obviously, if the length of the hyperlink ever varies from the 43 and 44 character length, the first part of the if statement will not work and the link will become just a clickable link.  But, this will be a very easy thing to fix.  So far, this code addresses the issue.

Comment: Update - just thought I'd point out the obvious in case someone might have missed it. Adding an elseif statement to accomodate embedding vimeo videos is quite trivial.  Was able to modify the youtube rules for vimeo content very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

[`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) is used to find the position of occurence of a substring inside a string.

To compare the strings, you can use:

```
if(strcmp($message,"youtube.com/watch?v=") == 0)
```

Or, as Mark Baker suggested in the comments, use strict comparison:

```
if($message === "youtube.com/watch?v=")
```

It will evaluate to `TRUE` only if `$message` is equal to and of the same type (string).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Try this

```
<?php
$t="youtube.com/watch?v=";
if ($t == "youtube.com/watch?v=")
  {
  echo "match";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  If $message contains "Test https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66kIF-iO5oQ test", then it conforms to the first if statement and the link comes back messed up.  I need the above to be ignored by the first statement and be processed by the else :(